# Conditionally format empty cells in rHandsontable in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

Q1: I would like to change the format of a rhandsontable cell in Shiny when its content become empty.
I thought I found it using `hot_cols(renderer = "...")` but I am quite surprised of the result: cells with content 0 are also highlighted. Could someone tell me how should I test emptyness in JS through R?
I tried `value === ''` and isEmpty() without any success.

Q2: Additionnally, if we enter "1e6" in column 3, the value which appears is indeed 1000000 but its background switch to red: any way to prevent it? i.e. to allow scientific notation input?

Here's a minimal reproductible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

DF <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, 0, 3), col2 = c(letters[23:22], NA), col3 = round(rnorm(3, 1e6, 1e3),0))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$rt <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(DF) %>%      
      
      # conditional overall formatting > grey empty cells
      hot_cols(renderer = "
           function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
             Handsontable.renderers.NumericRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
             if(!value) {
                td.style.background = '#EEE';
              }
           }")
  })
})

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput("rt")
))

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first question: you can add the condition that the value is not 0:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

DF <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, 0, 3), col2 = c(letters[23:22], NA), col3 = round(rnorm(3, 1e6, 1e3),0))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$rt <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(DF) %>%      
      
      # conditional overall formatting > grey empty cells
      hot_cols(renderer = "
           function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
             Handsontable.renderers.NumericRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
             if(!value && value != 0) {
                td.style.background = '#EEE';
              }
           }")
  })
})

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput("rt")
))

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Regarding your second question: it's a known [bug](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/2030) that was only fixed in `handsontable` 6.2.1, but the CRAN version of `rhandsontable` uses `handsontable` 6.1.1. The development version seems to be updated to 6.2.2, so you could install it from https://github.com/jrowen/rhandsontable

Comment: I was so sure there was a specific way to test both at the same time... I didn't think of this obvious solution :)
Why do you use "&&" and not just "&"?

Comment: I don't know much javascript, but I think the [logical AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) in JS is `&&`